# Import existing project failing in AndroidStudio

Tags: android

Trying to use the new AndroidStudio to open one of my Eclipse Android projects. I followed the steps and update the ADT plugin to the latest version. Then did the export from Eclipse generating the Gradle build file.

All went well. But when I try to import it into AndroidStudio using the existing sources option I get a dialog that says:

`"Source files for your project not found"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add JAVA_HOME with path of your jdk(in my case is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38") in environment variable.
2. Add ANDROID_HOME with path of android sdk(in my case is "D:\AndroidSDK") in environment variable.